# Javascript object methods evaluate functions

Tags: javascript, dom-events

first of all, I'm new to javascript.
my question is how can I add an event listener to the button and call the function from the myObj script. I tried to google but I don't know what is the keyword for that. thank you

```html
<div id="my-btn"></div>

<script>
    myObj.button('my-btn',{
        onClick: function() {
            alert('Button is clicked !');
        },
        onCancel: function() {
            alert('You cancel the process !');
        }
    });
</script>
```

and my object

```js
var myObj = {
    button: function(btnId, methods)
    {
        var btn = document.getElementById(btnId);

        for (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.toLowerCase() == 'onclick')
            {
                //btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                //}

                // i want to add listener
                // and call the function "onClick"

            }
        }

        // render button
        btn.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="My Button"></button>';
    }
}
```

thank you for your advice.

Comment: `btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(e) { ... put your handling code here }` - there it's called onClick, and it will execute whatever code you put inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-btn"></div>
    </body>
    <script>

    const myObj = {
        button: (btnId, methods) => {
            const btn = document.getElementById(btnId);

            for (let method in methods) {
                const nameLower = method.toLowerCase();

                if (nameLower.startsWith('on')) {
                    btn.addEventListener(nameLower.substr(2), function(e) {
                        methods[method]();
                    });
                }                
            }

            // render button
            btn.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="My Button"></button>';
        }
    };

    myObj.button('my-btn',{
        onClick: () => alert('Button is clicked !'),
        onCancel: () => alert('You cancel the process !')
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

We can map the function names to their events by converting to lowercase and stripping off the `"on"` prefix. So `onClick` becomes `click`. You could simplify things by just using the standard event names in your call to `myObj.button`.

Start by iterating over the functions, map the name and add the event listener. Inside the event listener all we do is call the function provided in the arguments.